# py2exe doesn't import the os module?

Tags: python, import, module, python-2.7, py2exe

So, basically, I'm trying to make my Python 2.7 script into an EXE. Here is my setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import os

setup(
     options = {
          "py2exe":{
              "includes": ["os"]
              }
          },  
  name = "Anansi CalcPad",
  version = "0.35",
  description = "Anansi CalcPad is a three-tiered application that provides a journal, calculator, and news aggregator in one.",
  author = "Cody Dostal",
  author_email = "cody@seafiresoftware.org",
  url = "http://seafiresoftware.org/wordpress/anansi-calcpad/",
  windows = ["AnansiCalc.py"],
  )
```

If there is indentation problems, it was caused by a bad copy on StackOverflow's part, not in the code.

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AnansiCalc.py", line 3, in <module>
ImportError: No module named os
```

What is wrong?

Comment: It doesn't look like the script is using anything in the os module. Try commenting-out the offending import.

Comment: It does it even without. My main script extensively uses os. This is just the setup script. It imports my main script, AnansiCalc.py, and it *requires* the os module :\

Comment: So is the os module found in your main script when it's run normally?

Comment: Yes. It imports it and it run's _perfectly_. Basically, I use it many times to conjoin directory and filename into one way to replace scripts on updates, etc... It's used about 10-20 times throughout the script, if not more. For other things too.

Comment: Well, at least that means your core Python installation is OK. The only thing I can suggest is try eliminating (commenting-out) code to try to determine what is causing the problem. Fortunately there's only two lines before the `import os` so doing so should be easy. Could be the standard Python search path `sys.path` is getting clobbered somehow by one of them.